# Connection string in app.config

Tags: c#, excel

how to add this C# code connection string in app.config file for windows forms application program ?
i see examples of adding access db but i need to add excel file data , so can't find previous question on excel file connection in app.config.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\MISD_report.xlsx" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
```

Comment: This question features an example of adding it to app.config.

Comment: i re-edited my question.

Comment: I believe it remains the same, just the `connectionString` attribute contains the Excel file. It looks like you've already got a valid connection string. The linked question was more demonstrating what to do with the provider details.

Comment: You can store every single part of the connection string as and individual key, and build a string (connection string) from those parameters in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in web config file-

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0'" />
<add name="ConnStrName" connectionString="Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=database-name;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=your username;Password=your password" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Error is {"An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'."}

Answer (score 1):

i solved this myself .

app.config settings :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MSIDConn" 
       connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\MISD_report.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0'" 
          providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

added these 2 lines in Form1.cs

using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

in button click event :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string excelconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MSIDConn"].ConnectionString;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = excelconn;

        OleDbCommand command9 = new OleDbCommand
        (
            "SELECT P1, P2, P3 " +
              " FROM [PE_Actual$] ", conn
        );
        DataSet ds9 = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adaptor9 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command9);
        adaptor9.Fill(ds9, "testtable");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds9.Tables[0].DefaultView;



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually they sit in a section on their own:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionName" providerName="myProvider" connectionString="Data Source=D:\MISD_report.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I do not know what the providerName for OLE/ Excel is or what name to use so the provider finds the correct connection string.

Comment: <configuration>
  
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MSIDConn" providerName="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" connectionString="Data Source=D:\\MISD_report.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0" />
    </connectionStrings>

</configuration>

Comment: I assumed that was the provider name, but was not sure since I am not accessing excel via ACE OLE

Comment: i got error as "{"An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'."}"